# Getting Variables on AJAX POST Process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to POST something via AJAX but have a little problem which I couldn't solve.

I have a PHP foreach loop and a delete function. Basically, I want to delete some items in this foreach with AJAX POST request. I can make POST thing but can not get ID value. ID value is too important for me, 'cause system should know which data will delete.

You can find my PHP code below:

```
<tbody>
 <?php foreach($contactMessages as $c) { ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $c['name']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $c['subject']; ?></td>
   <td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" id="delete"></td>
  </tr>
 <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#delete').click(function() 
     { 
      $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/messages/delete/'); ?>',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {'submit':true},
     });  
     });
</script>
```

As I said, I have to `POST` unique ID but couldn't find how to get it via JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You somehow need to store value in your `DOM` to be accessed for `http` request. Also note that you should not have multiple `ids` with same name in a `document`

Try this:

```js
 $('.delete').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $.ajax({
     url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/messages/delete/'); ?>',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
       'submit': true,
       'id':id
     },
   });
 });
```

```html
<tbody>
  <?php foreach($contactMessages as $c) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?php echo $c['name']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <?php echo $c['subject']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" class='delete' data-id='<?php echo $c['id']; ?>'>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php }?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I just tried it with a few items(foreach items) and there is a problem. It only gets first item's value, that's strange.

Comment: Just check the edit. You need to use class selector for event binding. I missed it earlier. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what devices/browsers you intend to support, you could add an HTML5 data attribute to your anchor tag.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" data-contact-message-id="<?php echo $c['id']; ?>">
```

Remove the id from the anchor as it meant to be unique in your DOM.

Then in your javascript, just before the ajax call, retrieve the value from the element.

```
var id = $(this).data('contact-message-id');
```

You'll be able to add it to your posted data at that point.